# How do I set administrator menu to be the same as this Drupal 7 menu?

Tags: 7, routes

I upgraded my site from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.

The administrator menu is looks differently with Drupal 7 aministrator menu.

How do I set it same as the default Drupal 7 menu?

***Drupal 7 administrator menu after upgrading***

[image]

***I want it became this administrator menu***

[image]

Comment: @othermachines Thanks. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable the menu shown in your first image, go to *Structure > Blocks* and disable any menu blocks you don't want to display (e.g., Management, Navigation, User). (Thanks, @leymannx!)

To have the menu shown in your second image, enable the core Toolbar module.

Comment: ...and remove the admin menu block from your sidebar under `admin/structure/block`.